# Deployment of spring application on kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I am going to create a kubernetes cluster to deploy all my spring boot microservices. Currently I have a spring cloud gateway server, a eureka discovery server and my back-end and front-end applications.

Do we need gateway server and discovery server if deployed on kubernetes, as these services are provided as part of cluster?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this what you're looking for?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#cloud-native-service-discovery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not required to use the Spring Cloud Gateway or Eureka discovery server. Kubernetes provides all basic building blocks (like *Service*) implemented without additional software requirements (for example with plain DNS).

If you need a more advanced setup you can integrate kubernetes API in Spring applications or use other ways to integrate. For the 90% case there is no need to do so.